# Vmware web development kit

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, mount, virtual-disk

I am using Virtual Disk Management Kit v5.0 [link](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?productId=229&downloadGroup=VDDK50).
The command i am using is

```
C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Virtual Disk Development Kit\bin>vmware-mount I:
C:\Users\Rushil\Documents\Virtual Machines\Ubuntu\Ubuntu-s001.vmdk
```

Unfortunately the above command does nothing except that every time i run it a (sort of)  vmware-mount man page is displayed on the command prompt telling about other command options. Any solutions ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space in your path to the vmdk and surely need to quote it:

```
vmware-mount I: "C:\Users\Rushil\Documents\Virtual Machines\Ubuntu\Ubuntu-s001.vmdk"
```